# Autocomplete with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

can someone please help me debug this code, I'd like to use 'react-native-autocomplete-input' library to autocomplete a search text input, basically the api request return a list of stock symbols and company names and I'm thinking to store this file locally to make it faster, for right now I just want to make it work using fetch. The autocomplete must search in `responseJson.symbol`

Here's what I've done so far:

```
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Platform,
        ScrollView, View, ActivityIndicator,
        } from 'react-native';

class AutocompleteExample extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      symbols: [],
      query: '',
    };
  }

searchSymbol(query) {
  if (query === '') {
      return [];
    }

const { symbols } = this.state;
const url = `https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols`;

fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({
      symbols:responseJson.symbol,
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
return symbols;
}

render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }
    const { query } = this.state;
    const symbols = this.searchSymbol(query);

    return (

      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 12,marginBottom:10}}> Type your favorite stock</Text>
        <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize={true}
          containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
          data={symbols}
          defaultValue={query}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
          placeholder="Enter symbol"
          renderItem={({ symbol }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: symbol })}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                {symbol}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />


      </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

MainContainer :{
  justifyContent: 'center',
  flex:1,
  paddingTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 20,
  padding: 5,
},
autocompleteContainer: {
  borderWidth: 1,
  zIndex:999,
  borderColor: '#87ceeb',
},
itemText: {
  fontSize: 17,
  color:'#000000',
}
});

module.exports = AutocompleteExample
```

I don't see any error on the console and the api request is working correctly, I just can't access `symbols const` Do I have to render something like `cloneWithRows(responseJson.symbols)` ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the searchSymbol method should be either [binded](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) in the component constructor, or declared as a [class property](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). Otherwise, "this" will not point to the component instance.

Then, it seems that your state does not have an isLoading property, but you use it in your render function.

What you should probably do is call your asynchronous searchSymbol method in the componentDidMount lifecycle method. When the promise of the fetch resolves, you should put the result in the state as well as put the isLoading boolean to false. Then your component will re-render with the now available data.